# Paypal:IPN Listener not receiving IPN messages

Tags: asp.net-web-api, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I have a website with online transaction using paypal as payment option. Checkout and the shopping cart calculations on paypal side are working, but i'm not receiving any IPN messages from paypal sandbox. after writing the log I found out that parameter *formdata* is null. Even checked with the IPN history and it shows the status of IPN message as retrying... IPN notification url has also been set.
Below is the listener code.

```
[Route("IPN")]
    public IHttpActionResult IPN(FormDataCollection formData)
    {

        var formVals = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        formVals.Add("cmd", "_notify-validate");

        string response = GetPayPalResponse(formVals, formData);

        if (response.ToUpper().Trim() == "VERIFIED")
        {

            //entry into database

            }
            else
            {

                return InternalServerError();
            }

        return InternalServerError();
    }

string GetPayPalResponse(Dictionary<string, string> formVals, FormDataCollection formData)
    {

        string paypalUrl = GetPayPalURL();
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(paypalUrl);

        // Set values for the request back
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var entry in formData.ToList())
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}={1}&", entry.Key, encoding.GetString(encoding.GetBytes(entry.Value)));
        }

        string strRequest = sb.ToString();
        strRequest += "cmd=_notify-validate";
        req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

        //Send the request to PayPal and get the response
        StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
        streamOut.Write(strRequest);
        streamOut.Close();

        StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
        streamIn.Close();

        return strResponse;
    }
```

This was working before, but no idea what had stopped it.
Being new to paypal payment gateway, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did anyone get this working...

Answer (score 1):

There is a certain problem with paypal since yesterday. I hope it is a remporary issue and it will be fixed asap. I have problems with sandbox myself, but it has happened before as well.

Comment: I am also having problems with Sandbox mode... can anyone else confirm this? I am using .NET SDK and adaptive payments...

Answer (score 0):

I am also having problems with Sandbox mode... can anyone else confirm this? I am using .NET SDK and adaptive payments...
EDIT: all working again today ;)